# How get all fields Api-Graph v2.8 of Facebook

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I want to try something that looks like this:

```
GET/v2.8/PageFacebook/posts?fields="all??"
```

This is because by default it does not bring me the "name" or "type" of the post. And I don't want to do the field-by-field consultation.

Comment: You need to ask for the fields you want, if you need anything more than the few default fields. Facebook introduced this to reduce the amount of data in API responses, particularly in regard to mobile. And that would just not work, if they still offered an option to get “all” data - because then every lazy dev out there would do that, instead of optimizing their code.

Comment: Ok. I imagined that was the reason. Thanks.

Answer (score 23):

If you want to have the list of all available fields, you need to do a query on a Post Id like this:

> GET/v2.8/PostId?metadata=1

Then you can make your selection and specify which fields do you want in your future request.
For instance:

> /GET/v2.8/PageFacebookId/posts?fields=id,promotion_status,target,shares,message_tags,source,place,event,parent_id,reactions.limit(0).summary(true),child_attachments,message,caption,story,full_picture,picture,link,name,description,type,status_type,created_time,comments.limit(0).summary(true),sharedposts,privacy,updated_time,story_tags,permalink_url,coordinates

Comment: I tried it but sadly doesn't work. It only brings me the default fields, which are just a few.

Comment: Oh true! You need to do it first on an object (a Post in your case)
so, you have to do it like this `GET/v2.8/postId?metadata=1`

Comment: From the comment above, it seems I can't get all the fields at once.